# Как изменить тип колонки float в int?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, типы-данных, обработка-данных

Хочу преобразовать в `int` колонки в `DataFrame`, но на выходе как были `float`, так и остались:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(mongo_docs)
datas = df.astype({'account':'int','binance_id':'int'},errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Если у вас в данных есть `NaN`, то `int` никак не получится - `NaN` есть только во `float`. Хотя в новейших версиях `Pandas` вроде собирались сделать `int` с `NaN`. Хотите сделать `int` - заполните сначала `NaN` каким-нибудь значением, и тогда всё получится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [относительно новым типом данных `Int64` (первая буква - большая)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
In [122]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, np.nan, 3]})

In [123]: df
Out[123]:
     a
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  3.0

In [124]: df.dtypes
Out[124]:
a    float64
dtype: object

In [125]: df = df.astype({"a": "Int64"})

In [126]: df.dtypes
Out[126]:
a    Int64
dtype: object

In [127]: df
Out[127]:
      a
0     1
1  <NA>
2     3
```

Comment: А, уже встроили, это хорошо. Попробовал на колабе - работает )

Answer (score 2):

Если в вашем датафрейме нет явных чисел с ненулевой дробной частью (не считая nan), например:

```
     a
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  NaN
4  4.0
5  5.0
```

то в pandas версии выше (если не ошибаюсь) 1.2.2, можно сделать простое приведение вида:

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

тогда получите:

```
      a
0     1
1     2
2     3
3  <NA>
4     4
5     5
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   a       5 non-null      Int64
dtypes: Int64(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можешь просто залочить 1 колонку и присвоить ей тип данных
используй библиотеку пандас

Например.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pandas.DataFrame(mongo_docs)
df["имя столбца"] = pd.to_numeric(df["имя столбца"])
```

если несколько столбцов то

```
df[["account", "binance_id"]] = df[["account", "binance_id"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

если у вас есть NaN то просто их уберите с помощью

```
df2 = df[pd.notnull(df['Имя столбца в котором есть NAN'])]
```

А потом уже делайте его целым

Comment: `df[:1]["account"]
0    1.0    `                        по любому float